# Jquery to calculate count of occurrences of element value in an XML file

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, count

Here's the XML I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinesOfBusiness>
 <Clients>
  <BusinessCategory>Restaurants</BusinessCategory >
  <PanelID>0001</PanelID >
  <BusinessName>Bobby's Pizza</BusinessName >
 </Clients>
 <Clients>
  <BusinessCategory>Restaurants</BusinessCategory >
  <PanelID>0002</PanelID >
  <BusinessName>Alberto's Mexican Restaurant</BusinessName >
 </Clients>
 <Clients>
  <BusinessCategory>Salons</BusinessCategory >
  <PanelID>0001</PanelID >
  <BusinessName>Beauty Queen Salon and Spa</BusinessName >
 </Clients>
 <Clients>
  <BusinessCategory>Salons</BusinessCategory >
  <PanelID>0002</PanelID >
  <BusinessName>Surf 'n' Tan Salon</BusinessName >
 </Clients>
 <Clients>
  <BusinessCategory>Salons</BusinessCategory >
  <PanelID>0003</PanelID >
  <BusinessName>Exquisite' Salon and Spa</BusinessName >
 </Clients>
</LinesOfBusiness>
```

I am trying to use JQuery to read an XML file and obtain a count of the number of "Clients" nodes with the same BusinessCategory Element (for example how many nodes with BusinessCategory = Restaurants, how many nodes with BusinessCategory = Salons etc). I have some code that is working with the node elements but I also want to get the count of nodes per specific BusinessCategory.

Here's the jquery I have:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var categoryName = url.split('/')[1];
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/clientcontent.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {

        $(xml).find('Clients').each(function () {
// do something with the elements within the XML
            var countClients = $(this).find("BusinessCategory = categoryName").length;
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error found in the data associated with this file")
    }
});
```

I am getting the value of **categoryName** just fine as **Restaurant** or **Salon** based on the URL of the HTML file (http://mydomain.com/Restaurants/Client0001.html for example) that calls this Jquery however I am getting countClients = 0. I think I am having a syntax error on that value assignment statement.

Can someone provide some insight on how I can resolve this? Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a string concatenation for `categoryName` since it is a variable, also you cannot use attribute selector here because `BusinessCategory` is not a attribute it is a child element with the searched text as its content

```
var countClients = $(xml).find('Clients > BusinessCategory:contains("' + categoryName + '")').length;
```

But I prefer to use .filter() because :contains will return partial matches so try

```
var countClients = $(xml).find('Clients').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).find('BusinessCategory').text()) == categoryName
}).length;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Y9LM/)

Comment: your second code segment is not working - I am getting the value = 0. However the first is working perfectly - I was having a fundamental issue with my code in that the var countClients was insider the each(function() ... so your first code segment was always returning the value = 1. I relocated that code segment containing the "contains" outside that each(function().. and it works like a charm. I am actually curious why your second code segment is not working. Anyway - thanks a ton :-)

Comment: @Joy fixed... it was my problem... there is no need for the each loop